# Backend Express API with react electron js front end

Tags: express, electron

I'm actually developing an Electron js app and idk if i can do a separate express js api ?
How can we do to put the EXPRESS app online ?
Am i obligate to get Express in my Electron js app ?
thanks

Comment: You can try using Google Cloud Function to deploy an API

Comment: i personally use an VPS but you can use whatever you want. Heroku is pretty popular. just go and explore it. even in their intro video the setup an small HTTP server https://www.heroku.com/nodejs